# CS1061 C# 'Player' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'Player' could be found

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I am relatively new to C# and Visual Studio and have been following a worksheet from an assignment, I have followed it line by line but have found 2 errors relating to the same issue and am unable to build and run it til they are fixed. Any help would be greatly appreciated

The error is the second Clubs marked bold and italic in the line:
`Clubs = b.Clubs.Select(a => new ClubDTO()`

```
// GET: api/Players/5
[ResponseType(typeof(PlayerDTO))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetPlayer(int id)
{
    Player b = await db.Players.FindAsync(id);
    if (b == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    PlayerDTO player = new PlayerDTO
    {
        PlayerId = b.PlayerId,
        Name = b.Name,
        Position = b.Position,
        Goals = b.Goals,
        Clubs = b.Clubs.Select(a => new ClubDTO()
        {
            ClubId = a.ClubId,
            TeamName = a.TeamName,
            Country = a.Country,
            League = a.League
        }

                      ).ToList()
    };
    return Ok(player);
}
```

Player:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Player
    {
        private ICollection<Club> _clubs;
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public int Goals { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Club> Clubs
        {
            get { return _clubs.ToList(); }
            set { _clubs = value; }
        }



    }
}
```

```
PlayerDTO

    
    namespace Project.Models
    {
        public class PlayerDTO
        {
            public int PlayerId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Position { get; set; }
            public int Goals { get; set; }
            public List<ClubDTO> Clubs { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your `Player` class code. Please add it to the question.

Comment: So there is no `Clubs` defined on your `Player` class. Maybe you should add that as part of your task?

Comment: GuruStron, there he initializes PlayerDto, not Player, so that property might exist in the dto. @Andrew could you please also provide the code for the PlayerDto class?

Comment: @JustShadow the error is in `Clubs = b.Clubs.Select(a => new ClubDTO()` according to OP, where b is `Player` with emphasis (which you removed) on `b.Clubs`

Comment: Oh now it's clear. Yes, that might be the root cause.

Comment: I edited the player.cs, would that be correct?

Comment: @GuruStron I just built the program and it worked, appreciate the help

Comment: @AndrewKelly was glad to help! It definitely will make your code compile, as for correctness - it depends on what you are actually need to do in the task. Also possibly you can use just [autoproperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).